# Order of redirection in bash & overwriting and appending at the same time

Tags: bash, redirect, file-descriptor

First, we have some commands:

```
service --status-all 1>one 2>one
service --status-all 1>two 2>>two
service --status-all 1>>three 2>>three
service --status-all 1>>four 2>four

service --status-all 2>one1 1>one1
service --status-all 2>two1 1>>two1
service --status-all 2>>three1 1>>three1
service --status-all 2>>four1 1>four1
```

After execution, the content of the following is the same:

***three = three1*, so these are equal:**

```
service --status-all 1>>three 2>>three
service --status-all 2>>three1 1>>three1
```

***one = four = one1 = two1*, so these are equal:**

```
service --status-all 1>one 2>one
service --status-all 1>>four 2>four
service --status-all 2>one1 1>one1
service --status-all 2>two1 1>>two1
```

***two = four1*, so these are equal:**

```
service --status-all 1>two 2>>two
service --status-all 2>>four1 1>four1
```

#### Contents of files:

Files *one* = *four* = *one1* = *two1*:

```
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ ? ]  binfmt-support
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  lightdm
 [ ? ]  mysql
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ ? ]  pppd-dns
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ ? ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
]  sudo
 [ - ]  udev
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ + ]  virtualbox
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Files *two* = *four1*:

```
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  brltty
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ + ]  friendly-recovery
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  pulseaudio
 [ + ]  resolvconf
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ + ]  saned
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ - ]  udev
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ + ]  virtualbox
 [ - ]  x11-common
nfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
```

File *three* = *three1*:

```
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ ? ]  binfmt-support
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  brltty
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ + ]  friendly-recovery
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  lightdm
 [ ? ]  mysql
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ ? ]  pppd-dns
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  pulseaudio
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ + ]  resolvconf
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ + ]  saned
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ ? ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ - ]  udev
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ + ]  virtualbox
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

There are 18 question marks (stderr lines). Stderr clearly overwrote first 18 lines of stdout and then some (sudo line).

Why such behaviour occurs?

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: "Overwrote first 18 lines of stdout"? What do you mean by this? One stream *can't* overwrite another; they're by definition different streams. Please explain in more detail what you interpret the behavior you're seeing to mean.

Comment: I suggest, by the way, that you might inspect your files in a manner that makes their control characters obvious/visible instead of letting those control characters impact their display to the screen. On a GNU system, using `cat -A one` and `cat -A one1` (separately, with a prompt between them) is likely to make things more clear. `cat one one1` leaves it intentionally ambiguous where one file ends and the other begins -- and if you have escape sequences or control codes in one that tell the terminal to modify content you saw from the other, results in questions like what we get here. :)

Comment: Could you try to filter the question down to just the case you're asking about? I don't see where you've shown that the two redirections behave differently. And all the other commands seem irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar I would have to paste a ton of results, the question would be deleted.

Comment: You could at least post the output of both `1>file 2>>file` and `2>>file 1>file`, so we could see the difference you're asking about.

Comment: @duppWR, ...or you could put in the time and effort to build a smaller reproducer, which would _not_ get your problem deleted. (There's a quote -- something along the lines of "I regret the length of this paper, but haven't the time to make it shorter"; asking a question both well and succinctly takes skill and effort, but it's a worthwhile task).

Comment: Why would you have to post a ton of results? There are only two cases you're asking about, all the rest are irrelevant.

Comment: ...and now, indeed, we have a ton of results (and no reproducer without a dependency on the external `service` program)... where we only needed two cases with a standalone reproducer for each.

Answer (score 1):

The stream that's opened for appending automatically repositions itself to the end of the file before each write. If the other stream writes to the file between two of its writes, it will reposition.

On the other hand, the stream that's open for normal output does not reposition itself. If the appending stream writes something, and then the normal stream writes something, the second write will overwrite what the first one wrote.

In addition, if the program uses `stdio`, some of the writes will likely be buffered. The above behavior occurs when the buffers are flushed, not when the program calls the buffered writing functions. By default, `stdout` is fully-buffered when writing to a file, `stderr` is unbuffered.

Answer (score 0):

The odd behavior you're seeing actually has nothing to do with redirection order, and everything to do with output buffering and flags passed to open().

You're opening one of your files with O_APPEND [as done by `>>`] -- so all writes will always go to the end -- and the other with `>` and thus lacking that guarantee. Further, as evidenced by the behavior you report, your program isn't doing line buffering for its writes, meaning that your writes get split into big chunks that aren't guaranteed to end at line boundaries and those chunks are interspersed.

If your program did line-buffered writes, you could use `>>` for both file descriptors and things would mostly work (as long as the lines were all short enough to be completed by a single `write()` call). It doesn't, though, so you simply can't split and recombine its output in this way and expect things to be split on line boundaries.

---

Now, to answer the literal question about redirection order (which has nothing at all to do with the actual cause of the problem at hand):

Left-to-right, strictly.